# Laravel 9 - How to prevent showing login page after user is logged-in and hit browser back button

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-authentication

How can I ensure that as soon as the user is logged-in in Laravel-9 he can no longer go to the login page via browser back button? 
I searched the internet for solutions. I have read in several places that it is not possible or that I have to use Javascript.
Just to be sure, I have decided to post my question here and I hope you can help me.
Is there any way to do this? If the solution is with javascript, how can I solve that with javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

if you open `guest` Middleware `/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` in your project, you can see the handle function with this condition:

```
       ...

  if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
  }
       ...
```

It means that after login to the site if users try to go to the login page, the browser redirects the page to the `HOME` address. So users cannot access the login page after logging into your site.
finally, in your `\routes\web.php` file, you must apply guest Middleware on your register route in this way:

```
Route::get('register',[RegisterController::class,'create'])->middleware('guest');
```

**Note:** you can edit `HOME` address from the `/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file.
This [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript/) lists several ways you could try to disable the back button via javascript, but none are guaranteed.

Comment: This is good research mate, i need to up vote you mate,

Answer (score 0):

By default Laravel 9 has the **RedirectIfAuthenticated** middleware under **App\Http\Middleware** which checks if the user is logged in **Auth::guard($guard)->check()** and *if they are they are taken to the /dashboard url* otherwise they are not. The Middleware is registered as **'guest'** in the **$routeMiddleware** array inside **Kernel.php**, this means that you can apply **guest** middleware to all routes that you do not need be accessed by logged in users.